# Delete from select by many columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Probably it's a simple question, many people asked similar questions before, but it's very hard to find an answer for my specific case.

I have a complex query like that:

```sql
SELECT val1, val2, val3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN ...
WHERE ...
HAVING ...
```

Now I want to delete some rows from another table (let's call it `table2`) after joining with the result of the previous statement. Like that:

`DELETE FROM table2 WHERE field1=val1 AND field2=val2 AND field3=val3`

Is it possible to do that with a single query?

Comment: Review Multiple-Table Syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html, post code attempt if you get into difficulty along with (as recommended https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ) sample data and expected outcome as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN operator as the following:

```
DELETE FROM table2 
WHERE (field1, field2, field3) IN
(
  SELECT val1, val2, val3
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN ...
  WHERE ...
  HAVING ...
)
```

See [more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) about using IN operator from the MySql reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual, section "Multi-Table Deletes"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#:%7E:text=block%20merge%20operations.-,Multi%2DTable%20Deletes,-You%20can%20specify) this syntax is one of the two given alternatives:

```sql
DELETE Table2
FROM Table2
  INNER JOIN Table1
WHERE Table1.val1=Table2.val1 
  AND Table1.val2=Table2.val2
  AND Table1.val3=Table2.val3;
```

Also note, that your are deleting rows and not table(s).